# Automatically filling in data types for <CollectionType>.empty[] in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

The following type of code is quite frequent in `scala` method parameters:

```
events: Map[BpmId, Seq[BpmEvent]] = Map.empty[BpmId, Seq[BpmEvent]],
```

So *theoretically* after having provided the type information and the `Map.empty` the IDE should be able to fill in the rest for us:

```
events: Map[BpmId, Seq[BpmEvent]] = Map.empty[**IDE fills in the types for us**],
```

However I have not discovered an Intellij built-in or plugin function to provide that feature.  Is there such an animal?

Comment: It would be nice if IntelliJ could do that, but in situations like this why not just use `Map()` to set the default as an empty `Map`?

Comment: @jwvh  That would be fine - but my recollection is that results in warnings. Checking now ..

Comment: @jwvh  That *does* work fine.  At some point I had been led to believe that were not sufficient. Please feel encouraged to put up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For method arguments, the use of `Map()` as a default empty-Map value is an option. Type information is preserved.